# Derivative with respect to a element of vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$$f(w)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-w^Tx}}$$
How do I find derivative of $f(w)$ with respect to $w_i$ where $w,x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^D$ ?

Do I simply find partial derivative with respect to w?
Where can I find tutorials/resources for this kind of question?

Answer (score 1):

We just need to carefully follow through on the chain rule. First, observe that $\newcommand{\pd}[1]{\frac{\partial}{\partial #1}}$

\begin{align}
  \pd{w_i} \left(1 + e^{-w^Tx} \right)^{-1} 
  &= - (1+e^{-w^tx})^{-2} \cdot \pd{w_i} \left(1 + e^{-(w_1 x_1 + \cdots + w_n x_n)}\right) \\
&= -(1+e^{-w^Tx})^{-2} e^{-(w_1x_1 + \cdots + w_n x_n)} \cdot \pd{w_i} \left[-(w_1 x_1 + \cdots + w_n x_n)\right] \\
&=-(1+e^{-w^Tx})^{-2} e^{-(w_1x_1 + \cdots + w_n x_n)} \cdot(-x_i) \\
&= x_i \frac{e^{-w^Tx}}{(1 + e^{-w^Tx})^2},
\end{align}
as needed.